# knockout: valueUpdate on change from javascript code

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

Hi  i know valueUpdate: afterkeydown will do model update after user input but I want to know how can i do valueUpdate automatically after some other javascript code changes value

I have a js code that does document.getElementById("input").value = "new value";

do i have to update model manually or what valueUpdate should i use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you trigger the `change` event for the element, then the element's binding (`value`) will pick up the change and process it normally.

However, generally you would want to make your updates through the view model and let the bindings handle setting the element's properties, but if you have 3rd party or existing code that interacts directly with the element that cannot be changed, then triggering the `change` event is a solution.

Knockout does include a utility to trigger an event properly cross-browser called `ko.utils.triggerEvent`.

Your code might look like:

```
   var elem = document.getElementById("input");
   elem.value = "new value";
   ko.utils.triggerEvent(elem, "change");
```

Comment: It's things like this that make Knockout so much easier to integrate into an existing code base. I had a zip code lookup that used an ajax call to fetch the city and state and update the form, but wasn't updating the view model. This was enough to make it work; won't update the zipcode lookup until all the pages that use it are using knockout. Thanks!

Comment: It works great in my 'paste' handler. But I wonder why data-bind="value: some, valueUpdate: 'paste'" didn't work?

Comment: Can I pass using jquery like $(thisid).parent().parent().find(".classname") inplace of document.getElementById("input")

Answer (score 1):

After the line that updates the input value, call observable.valueHasMutated() on whichever observable corresponds to the input you're changing.

Comment: Calling `valueHasMutated` will propagate the model value out to any subscribers (bindings) and overwrite the manual change that was made. In this case, you would want to trigger the `change` event, so that the `value` binding picks up your change.